# How to filter the dynamoDB table items based on a specific value of the attribute?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have the below content in the DynamoDB table:

```
Names   Read_Write    Read_Only
--------------------------------
name1   1966
name2   1296
name3   2345          1296
name4   1296
```

- Names, Read_write and Read_only are the 3 attributes/columns of the table.
- Names is the partition key.

I need to filter for rows/items that does not contain 1296.

I tried using the below logic but it does not seem to work:

```py
ProjectionExpression="Names, Read_write, Read_only",
FilterExpression=Attr('Read_write', Read_only).NOT_CONTAINS(1296)
```

I'm using python to do this implementation.
Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Given the small excerpt of the code I'm going to make some assumptions.

What you need to create is an and-filter that combines the two attributes.

It should looks something like this:

```py
FilterExpression=Attr("Read_Write").ne(1296) & Attr("Read_Only").ne(1296)
```

The ampersand is used to concatenate different conditions with a logical `AND`.

**References:**

- [Boto3 docs for dynamodb conditions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/dynamodb.html#boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Attr)
- [Condition chaining](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#querying-and-scanning)

---

### Update

You ended up going with the solution below, which uses contains, but is otherwise logically equivalent to the one I proposed. The `|` is the logical `OR`

```py
FilterExpression=~((Attr("Read_Write").contains(1296)) | (Attr("Read_Only").contains(1296)))
```

I don't entirely understand why your solution works and mine doesn't because from a purely logical perspective they should be equivalent:

```
(A != B) ^ (C != B)  = not ((A = B) v (C = B))
```

Anyway - as long as it works for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Should the input to .ne function be of a specific type or format ? @Maurice

Comment: I guess that depends on the datatype of your attribute. It it's a number, it should be an `int` or `Decimal` (not `float`) and for strings it should be of type `str`.

Comment: @BharathBharath if this helped, feel free to accept the answer so other know that the problem is solved.

Comment: Sadly, this does not work.
The solution that worked for me is:
FilterExpression=~((Attr("Read_Write").contains(1296)) | (Attr("Read_Only").contains(1296)))
@Maurice

Comment: I'm confused, didn't you specify you wanted items that neither contain 1296 in their Read_Write nor their Read_only attribute? My expression should work for that. Yours would return all those, where 1296 is present in Read_Only or Read_Write, which seems like the opposite of what you specified in the question :D

Comment: No. There is a "~" symbol in my expression at the start. Please observe. This would give me the results that does not contain 1296... @Maurice

Comment: Ah, you're right - missed that one. This should still be logically equivalent unless `contains` does something weird --> Boolean logic `(A != B) ^ (C != B)  = not ( (A = B) v (C = B))` - I'll update my answer to include the solution you proposed.